# Stop msi silent installation in-between and rollback the changes

Tags: windows-installer, wmi, rollback

I am installing a msi file on remote machine silently. But not able to find a way to stop the ongoing silent installation and provide an user a option to rollback the changes which the half installed package has made.

I used WMI classes to install the msi package silently.
Could anyone help me on stopping and roll-backing the msi silent installation, in-between the installation process.

Please do your valuable comments and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer setups don't fail halfway and leave a half-installed product on the system. They are transactional, and if they fail then they roll back and undo any changes made to the system. If you created the MSI and there are custom actions that have altered the system then create rollback custom actions to undo those changes. If it's some other MSI that leaves changes on the system when it fails then it's been poorly designed and authored.

Comment: I think you did not get my question. I want to knowingly stop the silent msi installation and one more thing which I want to clear is that I am not creating msi installer, I am just installing it using WMI classes and want a way to cancel/stop the ongoing silent installation.

Comment: Most that my team reviews are poorly authored.

Comment: A silent install is really a silent install, you can't have it silent and also offer the user a choice. If it's a test scenario then have a property passed on the command line that causes a deferred custom action to fail that triggers the rollback.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what you are trying to do is test that the rollback of any given MSI works.  Windows Installer XML has a nice [WixFailWhenDeferred Custom Action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixfailwhendeferred.html) pattern to do this. It would possible to author this into other MSIs using a transform.

Please note that many MSI authors don't have a clue about how to write high quality MSIs so don't be surprised if many of your installer behave badly when testing rollback.